# Excel VBA - movefile syntax

Tags: vba, excel

Please help with the code for copying files one by one to the destination folder. I tried with "for Each loop but it is copying all the files at once to the destination folder. I am new to to vba and would be helpful if someone could crack the code for me. thanks in advance. here's the code i have managed to come up with.

I am getting run time error 53, File not found,e highlighting the below syntax.

```
FSO.movefile Source:="C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\Outlookemails_Macro\" & Fname, Destination:="C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\TcktIDfolder\" & Fname

Sub Example1()

'Extracting file names Dim objFSO As Object Dim objFolder As Object Dim newobjFile As Object    
Dim lastID As Long Dim myRRange As Range Dim Maxvalue As Integer    
Dim sFolder As String Dim dFolder As String


Sub Example1()

'Extracting file names
Dim FSO
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim newobjFile As Object
Dim FromDir As String
Dim ToDir As String    

Dim lastID As Long
Dim myRRange As Range
Dim Maxvalue As Integer    
Dim Fname As String                    

FromDir = "C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\Outlookemails_Macro\"
ToDir = "C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\TcktIDfolder\"    
Fname = Dir(FromDir)

If Len(FromDir) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files"
    Exit Sub
End If    

Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")    
Maxvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)    
lastID = Maxvalue

'finding the next availabe row    
erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Extracting file names

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\Outlookemails_Macro")

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path        
For Each newobjFile In objFolder.Files

     'print file name       
    Cells(erow, 1) = Fname    

    'print file path
    Cells(erow, 2) = newobjFile.Path

    'PrintUniqueID
    Cells(erow, 3) = lastID + 1

    FSO.movefile Source:="C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\Outlookemails_Macro\" & Fname, Destination:="C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\TcktIDfolder\" & Fname     
    Cells(erow, 5) = "file succesfully copied"                   
Next newobjFile        

Set FSO = Nothing
Set newobjFile = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing             

End Sub
```

Comment: you are using Fname for the filename, but Fname is initialized with the return from `Dir` at the start of the proc (and will be "C:\Users\wazeer.ahamed\Documents\Outlookemails_Macro\" )

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code can be more simple and dynamic if you play with your own excel file.

- Use "A1" range to put the source folder.
- Use "B:B" range to put the
  name of the files.
- Use "C:C" range to concatenate the previous
  columns.
- Use "D1" range to put the destination folder.

---

```
Sub copyFiles()
'Macro for copy files
'Set variable
Dim source As String
Dim destination As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim destinationNumber As Integer

destinationNumber = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Create the folder if not exist
If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1"), 16) = "" Then
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")
End If

'Run the loop to copy all the files
For x = 1 To destinationNumber
    source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & x)
    destination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")
    FileCopy source, destination
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

With this you can change the folders' paths and file names whenever you want. I've used FileCopy to preserve your files in the source but if you need to delete it's better use other method.